# Stripping images from post teasers/excerpts in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

In my theme I'm trying to display the excerpts or teasers of child pages, yet I do not want to display any images, I want image tags stripped out.

Once I've gotten the teaser in all its html glory in a php variable, how do I strip out the img tags prior to using echo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And after you got the content in a html variable a small regular expression should do the rest

```
$content = preg_replace("/<img(.*?)>/si", "", $content);
```

Should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the semantics of  in your pages, similar to how post excerpts work.  You can get the list of subpages http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_pages from here and then iterate over them (the above document has an example for styling the names of pages).  you can then get the page contents with a custom function and do whatever you want with it.

http://www.mattvarone.com/wordpress/functionsphp-wordpress-themes/

That url explains how to add your own custom functions to a given theme.

Comment: I already have the content of the posts using a custom function. The problem is I have html content in a php variable, and if the first thing in that post is a giant image, my blog would end up looking broken when that excerpt is displayed as a huge image after I call echo

Comment: Sorry,  I didn't answer the question you asked.  There is an answer that uses regex above, which is an acceptable solution.  There is a function in the php language, strip_tags, http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php  that provides basic sanitization (you can specify a list of allowed tags). You can also use a real parser for XHTML.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `the_excerpt()` which automatically grabs just the text or you can use a more sophisticated version of the same thing called [The Excerpt Reloaded](http://guff.szub.net/2005/02/26/the_excerpt-reloaded/)